# Php script to compile c++ file and run the executable file with input file

Tags: php, c++, c

I need a php script to compile C/C++ file.
After compiling and getting the executable of that file i need to run that file with a argument of input.txt file and then compare the result with output.txt file

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Call a command-line C++ compiler using [system](https://www.php.net/system), [exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), or [backticks](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php). There is no C++ compiler written in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Is PHP required?  If not consider [GNU Make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/).  It was especially developed to solve such problems as your.  With this simple `Makefile`:

```
OUT = app
CFLAGS = -O2 -Wall

$(OUT): main.o

clean:
        rm -rf $(OUT) main.o
```

You get ability to easy compile your program with different compiler flags and performing clean operations:

```
make           # for compiling
make clean     # for remove binaries
```

`Make` has a [good manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html).  Also, there is similar tool from Microsoft called [nmake](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd9y37ha.aspx).