# Compile C code on Wamp Server

Tags: php, c, web-applications

For my graduation I need to build an online IDE. I have thinked to use a web-based IDE (Codiad), but I can't compile C code. I'm using WAMP server.

This is the question: is there any method to have and use GCC compiler on WAMP Server? Or I need to build an other server (for example Ubuntu Server) and use shell command for compiling C code through PHP functions?

Thank you in advance and sorry for my English!

Comment: I believe the most common way to run `gcc` on Windows is via [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/).

Comment: see this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263316/compile-c-file-using-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using PHP `shell_exec()` or backticks (``)

> PHP supports one execution operator: backticks (``). Note that these are not single-quotes! PHP will attempt to execute the contents of the backticks as a shell command; the output will be returned (i.e., it won't simply be dumped to output; it can be assigned to a variable). Use of the backtick operator is identical to shell_exec().

```
<?php
   $myfile = fopen("newfile.c", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $txt = "#include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
      printf(\"Hello PHP-C world\");
      return 0;
    }";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    fclose($myfile);
    $tmp = `gcc -o outputfile newfile.c`;
    echo "<pre>$tmp</pre>";
    $output = `./outputfile`;
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

I test it :)

[image]

**Further reading [DOC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php)**

N.B : do that gcc shold be installed on your server and you should have permissions

> The backtick operator is disabled when safe mode is enabled or shell_exec() is disabled.

Comment: I have installed WAMP on my PC, how can I install GCC on the wamp directory?

Comment: I forgot your in windows machine ! now I am in linux I couldn't check further 
but this will be the solution http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/

Comment: i think you need to add 'echo `./outputfile`;' to execute.

Comment: Yeah, I have copied the MinGW files in the Wamp directory, but I don't know how to put them. Tomorrow I'm going to set up and Ubuntu Server on virtual machine for resolving the problem

Comment: I updated the answer and posted complete code ! if it is match with your problem, don't forget to mark as answer ! good luck

Comment: However, it could report the syntax error of C code.